# log out button in html

Tags: html, asp.net

i have a form and in this there is also a some text boxes and i apply validation like enter enter document name enter description etc and there is also a logout button in upper right corner when i want to logout and click on logout button then it shows me in form that enter document name ,enter description etc ..... i search but i didn;t find any solution ..in form html code which tag i placed in whole form 
like this

```
<>(tag which i need )
 here is my html form code
   <>
```

why this occur?

Comment: You need to disable the validation for this button. Check about `CausesValidation`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.causesvalidation(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add following attribute into your log out button

```
CausesValidation="false"
```

like following buton

```
<asp:Button ID="btnLogout" runat="server" Text="logout" CausesValidation="false"
                            OnClick="btnLogout_Click" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make two forms instead of one. Have a form for the logout button and one for the textboxes. When you post the logout form you just don't do validation...